# Select all statements using alternate identifier in Wikidata SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

When I use a Q ID to do a query, I can get *all* the statements and identifiers -- EVERYTHING, e.g.

```
SELECT ?value ?valueLabel ?prop ?propLabel {
    wd:Q112133367 ?prop ?value .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

This query successfully returns about 30 rows of data.

However, that assumes that I know the Q ID **in advance**.  I am trying to retrieve the same results, but using an external identifier, e.g. the IMDb ID because I don't know the Q ID in advance.

This query works to look up the Q ID given the IMDb external ID:

```
SELECT ?item  ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{ 
  ?item wdt:P345 "tt13276352"
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

But this only returns a single row of data (the Q ID).  I have tried adding some additional values to the query, but the query times out, e.g.

```
SELECT ?item  ?itemLabel ?foo ?prop ?value 
WHERE 
{ 
  ?item wdt:P345 "tt13276352" . 
  ?foo ?prop ?value .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

I am stuck thinking about this too much from the point of view of a relational database so I don't see how to select all the same bits of data as when I use the Q ID.

Comment: What means "unsuccessful"? Just add another triple pattern to get the triple for the item: `?item ?p ?o` and then also add the additional variables to the projection part of your query. Or do I misunderstand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question: unsuccessful means either that the query times out or that it only selects a single row of data when I want all the available statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have introduced an extra variable `?foo`.

Re-use the `?item` variable instead:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?prop ?value 
WHERE 
{ 
  ?item wdt:P345 "tt13276352" . 
  ?item ?prop ?value .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

[Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fprop%20%3Fvalue%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP345%20%22tt13276352%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Fprop%20%3Fvalue%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%7D) to Wikidata Query Service for the above.